# BIND: forward 1st level zone

Tags: bind, forwarding

First of all: sorry for the language, English is not my primary language.

I have star-like DNS structure with many filials (more that 2):

---

```
                                   ^
                                   |
                                   v
```

**filialNS_1.filial_1.city.local <----> ns.main.city.local <----> filialNS_2.filial_2.city.local**

```
                                   ^
                                   |
                                   v
```

---

- `ns.mail.city.local` is slave of all filials zones
- filialNS_1 is master of `filial_1.city.local`
- filialNS_2 is master of `filial_2.city.local`
- filialNS_N is master of `filial_N.city.local`

**I want to:**

1. serve DNS queries for `xxx.filial_N.city.local` with `filialNS_N.filial_N.city.local`
2. forward all queries for `xxx.xxx.xxx.local` from `filialNS_N` to `ns.main.city.local`
3. forward other queries to our provider's DNS on filial (or google-public-dns or anything else)

**FILIAL CONFIG named.conf**

```
zone "filial_1.city.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/namedb/dynamic/filial_1.city.local";
        allow-update {
                key DHCP_UPDATER;
        };
        allow-transfer {
                <ns.main.city.local IP address>
        };
};

zone "2.76.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/namedb/dynamic/2.76.10.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-update {
                key DHCP_UPDATER;
        };
        allow-transfer {
                <ns.main.city.local IP address>
        };
};

zone "local." {
      type forward;
      forward only;
      forwarders {
                <ns.main.city.local IP address>
      };
};
```

`nslookup server.filial_1.city.local` - works fine

```
nslookup server.main.city.local

Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find server.main.city.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It works.Thanks to [linux.org.ru](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/9341124?lastmod=1373286856889#comment-9341933)